# Remove Null Value in Multiple Dynamic Pivot Result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table

I want to use dynamic multiple pivot for my table. I successfully to pivot the table but the problem is there are a lot of NULL values.

This is my current result

[image]

And this is what I have tried:

```
 CREATE table #tempdata(
    Name Varchar(100),
    date date,
    MeterSN Varchar(100),
    Reading float,
    Usage VARCHAR(20),
    UsageValue float,
    RecordedBy Varchar(100),
    Remark Varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO #tempdata 
    SELECT  c.Name, a.date, b.MeterSN, a.Reading, c.Name + ' Usage' AS Usage, 
            Reading - LAG(reading) over(partition By currentMeterSNID order by a.date) as UsageValue,  
            a.RecordedBy, a.Remark 
                FROM INF_Facility_ElectricalRecord a
                    INNER JOIN INF_Facility_ElectricalMeter b ON b.id = a.currentMeterSNID
                        INNER JOIN INF_Facility_Location c ON c.id = b.LocationID
                            WHERE a.date BETWEEN '2019-03-19' AND '2019-03-20'
                                ORDER BY c.Name, a.date, b.MeterSN


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @cols2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Name) 
                        from #tempdata
                        group by Name
                        order by Name
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'')
    SELECT @cols2 = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Usage) 
                        from #tempdata
                        group by Usage
                        order by Usage
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'')

    set @query = 'SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),date,120) AS Date,' + @cols + ','+ @cols2 + ', recordedby AS [Recorded By] , remark AS Remark from 
                 (
                    select name,date, Reading, Usage, UsageValue, remark, RecordedBy
                    from #tempdata 
                ) x
                pivot 
                (
                    MAX(Reading)
                    for Name in (' + @cols + ')
                ) p 
                pivot 
                (
                    MAX(UsageValue)
                    for Usage in (' + @cols2 + ')
                ) p
                ORDER by date '

    execute(@query);
    drop table #tempdata
```

Is there any solution for my problem?

Comment: use conditional `case when` with aggregate function

Comment: @Squirrel can you give me some example?